# What happens to queued FastCGI requests when my server goes down?

Tags: c++, nginx, webserver, fastcgi, high-availability

I understand that FastCGI queues requests and acts on them one by one. I was wondering what would happen if there are multiple requests queued, and for some reason my server goes down. Will it still remember the requests and continue acting on them when the server springs back up or will I lose all those queued up requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will lose the queued requests. They are held in memory, not on disk.

Comment: Would you know of a way to retrieve or protect the requests from getting lost when the server goes down?

Comment: If your server goes down, the browser will lose the connection anyway, you won't have anyone to send the response to.  If your server really is likely to go down (are you sure?) then you need to architect your system differently, and take into account how your client will find the response.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have documentation for your FastCGI application to the contrary, I would assume that when the OS or hardware fails or shutdown, the requests in process will be lost. If you want to be certain, you can set up a test where some requests are queued, and then shutdown or unplug as needed to simulate the situation you want to test.